# How can I determine the EntitySet that an bound Operation (function or action) belongs to given a Microsoft.Odata.Edm.IEdmModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, odata

I have an **Microsoft.Odata.Edm.IEdmModel** and I am trying to determine what EntitySet each operation belongs to. But it doesn't seem possible.
I tried the following:

```
var edm = WebApiConfig.GetOdataEdmModel();
var operation = edm.SchemaElements.First(x => (x as IEdmOperation)?.Name == "GetRecentCustomers") as IEdmOperation;
var boundTo = operation.FindParameter("bindingParameter");
var matchingEntitySets = edm.EntityContainer.EntitySets()
                            .Where(x => x.Type.FullTypeName() == boundTo.Type.Definition.FullTypeName())
                            .ToList();
```

The problem is that *matchingEntitySets* can have more than one result. The reason is that the OData model is built this way:

e.g.,

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<BusinessEntity>("Customers");
builder.EntitySet<BusinessEntity>("Vendors");
builder.EntityType<BusinessEntity>()
       .Collection
       .Function(nameof(CustomersController.GetRecentCustomers))
       .ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<BusinessEntity>("Customers");
```

Is the answer simply that OData doesn't support more than one entity set with the same model type? If that is the case why doesn't the builder protect against this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is simply that there is more than one entity set referencing the same entity. I just took one of the entity set's and gave it it's own type, and that solved the issue.